# How to install phpThumb in codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, phpthumb

How to install phpThumb in codeigniter framework. I have placed the files like below floder struture

```
/uploads
/cache
/images
phpthumb.bmp.php
phpthumb.class.php
phpThumb.config.php
phpthumb.filters.php
phpthumb.functions.php
phpthumb.gif.php
phpthumb.ico.php
phpThumb.php
phpthumb.unsharp.php
```

When i place this phpThumb files in upload folder my webpage showing empty, when i remove those files then the webpage loading correct. How could i resolve this and let me know hopw to install the PHPThumb in my codeigniter framework

Answer (score 2):

Place pHP thumbe folder in root directory of project

Comment: I have placed root only.

Comment: use localhost/name/phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=/images/img.jpg&w=300&h=220 path